# How is a getter method of a class a Function<ThisObject, ReturnType> if a getter doesn't take in anything?

Tags: java, functional-programming

https://medium.com/quick-code/java-8-functional-programming-how-i-do-f11239a0aa90

I'm looking at this article because I was wondering how to implement getters in functional interfaces for long xml-type nested objects (basically trying to figure out if I can chain getters to get a deeply nested object that represents an XML tree).

The part that confuses me is how a getter is a `Function<City, String>`. Do non static methods always take in the object that the method corresponds to? I've read a lot of the docs but I don't see any of this mentioned. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Why City::getName not supplier? Getters don't take in anything.

Comment: Good introduction to the topic by Venkat Subramaniam a noted teacher and Java consultant, tend to be verbose but well worth the time  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15X0qFtBqiQ  or plenty of tutorial material on Java Functional programming online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to express City::getName, the lambda could also be written accordingly, maybe makes it more concise to understand what exactly happens:

```
final Function<City, String> getPrice = c -> c.getName();
```

Additional to the discussion, why is it a Function and not a Supplier:
In contrast to the Supplier, the Function takes an argument. So the use-case would be different.

1. With Supplier, you would always base on the same City, eg.

   ```
    final City city = currentCity
    supplier = () -> city.getName()
    // or
    supplier = city::getName
   ```
2. With Function<City,String>, you would always provide the instance to the Function:

   ```
    func = (city) -> city.getName()
    // or
    func = City::getName
   ```

Comment: Or `getPrice = c::getName`.